# Один элемент Tinymce на 6 textarea

Tags: javascript, tinymce, html

Как сделать, чтобы внутри дива все textarea редактировались одной панелем для редактирования?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Full featured example using jQuery plugin</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1");
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../jscripts/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
        $('div.tinymce').tinymce({
            // Location of TinyMCE script
            script_url : '../jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

            // General options
            theme : "advanced",
            plugins : "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,advlist",

            // Theme options
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,save",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
            theme_advanced_resizing : true,

            // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
            content_css : "css/content.css",

            // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
            template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
            external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
            external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
            media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

            // Replace values for the template plugin
            template_replace_values : {
                username : "Some User",
                staffid : "991234"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/dump.php?example=true">
        <div class="tinymce" style="width: 60%">
            <textarea id="elm" name="elm" rows="3" cols="60" style="width: 100%" >
                Это простой текст
            </textarea>
            <textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="3" cols="60" style="width: 100%">
                Это простой текст
            </textarea>
            <textarea id="elm2" name="elm2" rows="3" cols="60" style="width: 100%">
                Это простой текст
            </textarea>
            <textarea id="elm3" name="elm3" rows="3" cols="60" style="width: 100%">
                Это простой текст
            </textarea>
            <textarea id="elm4" name="elm4" rows="3" cols="60" style="width: 100%">
                Это простой текст
            </textarea>
            <textarea id="elm5" name="elm5" rows="3" cols="60" style="width: 100%">
                Это простой текст
            </textarea>
        </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

При использовании TinyMCE есть возможность делать подключение по CSS-классу. То есть при использовании кода

```
tinyMCE.init({
  mode : "textareas",
  editor_selector : "mcetxt",
  theme : "metroatom",
  content_css : "/css/style_discussion_form.css",
});
```

визуальный редактор подключится ко всем textarea.mcetxt.